# Is it a good Idea to wrap return values of functions?

Tags: c#, .net, function

Is it a good idea to wrap the return value of the functions in a class. It provides ease of coding and you can avoid try...catch
I'm taking about doing something like this.

```
public class ResultWrapper
{
    public bool Success{get;set;}
    public Exception ErrorMessage{get;set;}
    public object Result{get;set;} //not object essentially(any type) 

    public Result()
    {
            Success=false;
            ErrorMessage="";
            Result=null;
    }
}

public ResultWrapper DoSomething(parameters....)
{
    var result=new ResultWrapper()
    try
    {

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        result.Error=ex;
    }
    return result;

}
```

and then calling it like

```
static void main()
{
    var result=DoSomething(parameters...);
    if(result.Success)
    {
        //Carry on with result.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        //Log the exception or whatever... result.Error
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

consider this

```
static void main()
{
    var result=Login(); //throws an exception
    if(result.Success)
    {
        //retrive the result
        //carry on
        result=PostSomeStuff(parameter);
        if(result.Success)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to Post the data.\r\nError: {0}",result.Error.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to login.\r\nError: {0}",result.Error.Message);
    }
}
```

isn't it simpler then to wrapping a try..catch outside of each function???

```
static void main()
{
    try
    {
        var result=Login();
        var result1=result=PostSomeStuff(parameter);
        // a lot of functions doing seprate things.

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //what to do...?
    }

}
```

Comment: I think that exceptions were introduced to get rid of such wrappers with hundred of error codes.

Comment: This is a *very* generalized question. It's like asking whether you should return a `string` or an `int` - we can't really answer without more context...

Comment: Please don't follow the model of `ERROR_SUCCESS`. It is, as a rule, up to the caller to determine what exceptions are problems. A text editor may treat a file-not-found as cause to display a warning message box when a user tries to include a missing file. A reactor control system might want to treat a missing file as somewhat more, um, critical. If the only detail available is "not success" then the user experience, debugging, maintainability, ... all suffer.

Comment: @AbdullahSaleem so, check that: http://pastebin.com/cYhAvgUS . It was my sample for presentation about exceptions.

Comment: Don't forget that you can use multiple `catch` clauses to handle various exceptions separately. You can explicitly handle expected exceptions, e.g. bad username/password, and have a generic `catch` last for those odd exceptions that you didn't expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is an anti-pattern.  If there is any exception that you don't know how to handle then let it propagate up.  Returning exception objects in the return value is a very bad idea when the language has support for exceptions.

If the method is successful it should return the value directly; if it fails it should throw an exception.  (Caveat: Some methods might return `bool` indicating success or failure, and store the result in an `out` parameter.  For example, `int.TryParse()`, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue()`, etc.  Since exceptions can be expensive, some operations might be better suited to simply return a flag indicating failure *if failure is expected to be frequent*, but this should be a rare occurrence.)

Comment: While I'd say that's *generally* the case, I think for some operations the `TryXyz` pattern works very well - specifically with parsing. Having seen your edit - I think the ability to then get more details on parse failure is useful... hence Noda Time's encapsulated `ParseResult<T>`. They defer throwing the exception, but you can still do so when you want to.)

Comment: Just edited the post. My point is warping them tells you exactly which function threw the exception hence you can manage it accordingly and saves you the trouble to catching and throwing the exception within the function

Comment: @AbdullahSaleem You can determine exactly which function threw the exception by looking at the stack trace object.  But usually this isn't helpful except to someone trying to debug the code.  Can you show a real-life case where this would be helpful information to use during runtime?

Comment: @cdhowie consider the code posted in the edit. if an error occurs during login lets say 403(WebException) was thrown you know that something went wrong during the Login process perhaps the credentials were wrong hence you can just display a custom message. but if you don't wrap the result in a class you have to catch the exception within the login function and re throw it with a custom message...?

Comment: @AbdullahSaleem You can accomplish exactly the same thing by nesting `try` blocks within each other.

Comment: @cdhowie well yeah you can. I guess I'm over-thinking it

Answer (score 3):

Generally no.  There may be specific cases where it's a good idea, but I wouldn't recommend it as a default.

It will make it impossible to allow the exception to "bubble up" until it gets to a good place to handle it.  It will make the code harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is awful. Think how many if statement would be added to your code, just to check if an exception was thrown.

Also, think of it this way: if this were a great idea, then the .NET Framework itself would do this. Have you ever seen this pattern anywhere in .NET? I haven't.

You should almost always match the semantics of what the framework does that you are using, otherwise you end up with a weird mish-mash. Soon you have 10 competing coding "standards."